# How to get all the unique words in the data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe with a list of products and its respective review

+---------+------------------------------------------------+
| product | review                                         |
+---------+------------------------------------------------+
| product_a       | It's good for a casual lunch                   |
+---------+------------------------------------------------+
| product_b       | Avery is one of the most knowledgable baristas |
+---------+------------------------------------------------+
| product_c       | The tour guide told us the secrets             |
+---------+------------------------------------------------+

How can I get all the unique words in the data frame?

I made a function:

```
def count_words(text):
    try:
        text = text.lower()
        words = text.split()
        count_words = Counter(words)
    except Exception, AttributeError:
        count_words = {'':0}
    return count_words
```

And applied the function to the DataFrame, but that only gives me the words count for each row.

```
reviews['words_count'] = reviews['review'].apply(count_words)
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with this:

```
dfx
               review
0      United Kingdom
1  The United Kingdom
2     Dublin, Ireland
3    Mardan, Pakistan
```

To get all words in the "review" column:

```
 list(dfx['review'].str.split(' ', expand=True).stack().unique())

   ['United', 'Kingdom', 'The', 'Dublin,', 'Ireland', 'Mardan,', 'Pakistan']
```

To get counts of "review" column:

```
dfx['review'].str.split(' ', expand=True).stack().value_counts()


United      2
Kingdom     2
Mardan,     1
The         1
Ireland     1
Dublin,     1
Pakistan    1
dtype: int64    ​
```